# How to Load-balance Vora HANA connections

Tags: hana, vora

Is there a way to load balance hana servers in a Vora-Hana table that was made with
**'USING com.sap.spark.hana'** ?

In the OPTIONS section 'host' is specified, is it possible to have this point to multiple HANA hosts?
such as **"host" "hana1,hana2,hana3"**.

for example a 3+1 cluster, 3 active 1 standby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workload distribution of queries can be handled via HANA's statement routing mechanism (see [SAP Note 2079372 - SAP HANA - Statement Routing](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2079372); parameter in indexserver.ini -> [distribution] -> client_distribution_mode = [ off | connection | statement | all ]). The HANA datasource uses the HANA jdbc driver to connect to HANA - the current client default setting is distribution=ALL. By changing the parameter on the HANA side either a round-robin distribution or statement routing should be possible.

Comment: It is more, If I have "hana1" as a host in an application and that server goes down on the HANA side, If I run the job when it is down, does that keep that job from running. So the multiple hosts list would be more like "Data Services" where if one is down it will use the other to communicate to HANA.

Comment: NVM I understand what you mean

Comment: The original question was for load balancing on the HANA side. This is different from HA/failover in case of failures. There is currently no HA/failover support in the HANA datasource.

Comment: Ok. I just was wondering if I required to add logic into my job are if it was already handled through the statement. Either or to me. Thank You